# Returning arrays from Procedures in TCL

Tags: tcl

I  want to pass array and return array from a procedure, the following is the sample code i tried. But getting some errors..

```
set a(0) "11"
set a(1) "10"
set a(2) "20"
set a(3) "30"
set a(4) "40"

proc deleten somet {
    upvar $somet myarr
    for { set i 1} { $i < [array size myarr]} { incr i} {
        set arr($i) $myarr($i)
    }
    return arr
}

array set some[array get [deleten a]]
parray some
```

when i run this code i get the following error wrong # args: should be "array set arrayName list". I'm pretty sure that i dont want to use list, how can i set the array returned from the proc to another array???

Comment: That seems like a very odd thing to be doing in that code. Wouldn't it be simpler to just use `array set some [array get a];unset some(0)`?

Comment: In general, I suggest to use descriptive names for your variables and procedures. Names like `deleten` or `somet` do not convey your intention/purpose.

Comment: Taking a step back and it seems you can use a list instead of an array for your need. I say this because the indices are consecutive integers. Keep in mind that in Tcl, the *list* data structure is equivalent to *array* in other languages such as C or Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The step you were missing is that you return `[array get arr]` rather than just `arr`.

The following snippet works here

```
set a(0) "11"
set a(1) "10"
set a(2) "20"
set a(3) "30"
set a(4) "40"

proc deleten somet {
   upvar $somet myarr
   for { set i 1} { $i < [array size myarr]} { incr i} {
       set arr($i) $myarr($i)
   }
   return [array get arr]
} 

array set some  [deleten a]
parray some
```

See [How to pass arrays](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3262) for further information.

Comment: Appleman1234     I have posted the code i tried as an answer, Could you please me know where I'm going wrong?