# variables/arrays from tcl procedure

Tags: variables, tcl, procedures

How could i pass some variables/ arrays outside of procedure?

Lets say I've my procedure 'myproc' with inputparameters {a b c d e}, e.g.

```
myproc {a b c d e} { 
    ... do something
    (calculate arrays, lists and new variables)
}
```

Inside this procedure I want to calculate an array phiN(1),phiN(2),...phiN(18) out of the variables a-e which itself is a list, e.g.

```
set phiN(1) [list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
```

(lets say the values 1-9 had been calculated out of the input variables a-e). And I want to calculate some other parameter alpha and beta

```
set alpha [expr a+b];
set beta  [expr c+d];
```

Anyway no I want to pass these new calculated variables outside of my procedure. Compare to matlab I simply would write sg like to get these variables outside of the 'function'.

```
[phiN,alpha,beta] = myproc{a b c d e}
```

Has anybody an idea how I can deal in tcl?? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning arrays from Procedures in TCL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755182/returning-arrays-from-procedures-in-tcl)

Comment: Why you did not search first? Searching for questions mentioning two words, "array" and "procedure" tagged with the "tcl" tag brings a couple of already asked and answered questions.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I searched in a different direction. I searched how i can pass more than one variable out of an proc, but not especially for arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options:

1. **Return a list and use [`lassign`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lassign.htm) outside**
   Example:

   ```
   proc myproc {a b c d e} {
       set alpha [expr {$a+$b}]
       set beta [expr {$c+$d}]
       return [list $alpha $beta]
   }

   lassign [myproc 1 2 3 4 5] alpha beta
   ```

   This is fine if you return values, but not arrays.
2. **Use [`upvar`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/upvar.htm) and provide the name of the array/variable as argument**
   Example:

   ```
   proc myproc {phiNVar a b c d e} {
       upvar 1 $phiNVar phiN
       # Now use phiN as local variable
       set phiN(1) [list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
   }

   # Usage
   myproc foo 1 2 3 4 5
   foreach i $foo(1) {
        puts $i
   }
   ```
3. **Use a combination of both**
   Example:

   ```
   proc myproc {phiNVar a b c d e} {
       uplevel 1 $phiNVar phiN
       set alpha [expr {$a+$b}]
       set beta [expr {$c+$d}]
       set phiN(1) [list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
       return [list $alpha $beta]
   }

   lassign [myproc bar 1 2 3 4 5] alpha beta
   foreach i $bar(1) {
        puts $i
   }
   ```

**Edit**: As Donal suggested, is is also possible to return a dict:

A dict is a Tcl list where the odd elements are the keys and the even elements are the values. You can convert an array to a dict with [`array get`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm#M8) and convert a dict back to an array with [`array set`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm#M11). You can also use the [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) itself.
Example

```
     proc myproc {a b c d e} {
        set alpha [expr {$a+$b}]
        set beta [expr {$c+$d}]
        set phiN(1) [list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
        return [list [array get phiN] $alpha $beta]
    }

    lassign [myproc 1 2 3 4 5] phiNDict alpha beta
    array set bar $phiNDict
    foreach i $bar(1) {
         puts $i
    }
    # Use the [dict] command to manipulate the dict directly
    puts [dict get $phiNDict 1]
```

For more ideas (this is about arrays, but could apply to values as well) see [this wiki entry](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3262).

Comment: Also consider returning a dictionary; sometimes that makes more sense.