# Proc call to create Array and perform logical iteration per requirement

Tags: tcl

TCL Code

1. Build array on basis of command output value as source of input.
2. Perform logical iteration to identify the match and non match value to call for decision.

In this, I'm trying to write a proc call, which will return array matrix.
Post that, I will try to do array comparison with returned array, to find out what value I'm looking in array exist or not, and list out those value .

```
proc funcName { args } {
    puts "$args"
    for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $args]} {incr i} {
        set Element [lindex $args $i]
        puts $Element
        set Element1 [split $Element "*"]
        puts $Element1
        foreach {F1 F2} $Element1 break
        puts "$F1 -- $F2"
        #ARRAY define
        set Objectname($F1) "$F2"
        foreach index [array names Objectname] {
            puts "Objectname($index): $Objectname($index)"
        }
    }
}

set  Value " X: *ACTIVE | Y: *ACTIVE | Z: *INACTIVE | Q: *NONE "
set Object [ split "$Value" | ]
funcName $Object
```

```
X: ACTIVE
Y: ACTIVE
Z: ACTIVE
Q: NONE
```

On above mentioned block, I have requirement to do key search on element Z:INACTIVE , X: ACTIVE. Which I want to do dynamically and compare with each element, if in case found result say "Matched " and it's value.

Comment: Can you please clarify/insert current outcome and the desired outcome in the question? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Jerry    , Please find the link    https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1bAV

Comment: Are you saying that this is what you want the code to output?

Comment: Consider this is Input X: *ACTIVE | Y: *ACTIVE | Z: *INACTIVE | Q: *NONE .  The output expected to find out element Y:*ACTIVE and Q:*NONE dynamically while running a query inside Input . Please find the link https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1bGX

Comment: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1bHH .  I'm finding difficult to share the code , hence sharing the URL mentioned above  . At this stage I'm able to execute what required.  Could you possible share Edit question tab link OR training link .To send code or expected requirement in near future .Thank you

Comment: If you mean Tcl tutorials, I don't really have any. I am self taught and learned from different projects and the Tcl wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For how to return an array (summary: return a dictionary):

- [Returning arrays from Procedures in TCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755182/returning-arrays-from-procedures-in-tcl)

However, you've got substantial problems with your input and processing too. In particular, you probably ought to write:

```
proc funcName { args } {
    foreach Element $args {
        lassign [split $Element "*"] F1 F2
        set Objectname([string trim $F1 " :"]) [string trim $F2]
    }
    foreach index [array names Objectname] {
        puts "Objectname($index): $Objectname($index)"
    }
    return [array get Objectname]
}

set Value " X: *ACTIVE | Y: *ACTIVE | Z: *INACTIVE | Q: *NONE "
array set Object [funcName {*}[split $Value "|"]]
# Show we've really got it...
puts "$Object(X), $Object(Y), $Object(Z), $Object(Q)"
```

The key here is using `foreach` more, `string trim`, `lassign`, and the `{*}...` expansion syntax. Also `array get` and `array set` for copying the array out of the function.

Comment: I have written this set of code,Please refer the  Link  https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1bHn   .I 'm unable to debug output , Iteration execution is there , but something messy or disjoint exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what Vishal is asking for, given the string, make an array. Here is my attempt:

## Code

```
proc makePairs {strData} {
    set pairs {}
    foreach kv [split $strData "|"] {
        lassign [split $kv ":"] k v
        set k [string trim $k]
        set v [string trim $v " *"]
        lappend pairs $k $v
    }

    return $pairs
}

set  value " X: *ACTIVE | Y: *ACTIVE | Z: *INACTIVE | Q: *NONE "
array set ar [makePairs $value]
parray ar
```

## Output

```
ar(Q) = NONE
ar(X) = ACTIVE
ar(Y) = ACTIVE
ar(Z) = INACTIVE
```

## Notes

- In general, please choose descriptive names. Names such as `funcName`  or `Objectname` do not tell the readers their purposes, thus are meaningless. Good names help define the problem/solution
- My approach first split the string by `"|"`, then again by `":"`

Comment: Thank you Hai for your Input.  In above code I have to perform dynamic search for element ( example Z INACTIVE and  Y ACTIVE .Using Iteration logic. Link   https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/1bHn

Comment: @Vishal, I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please update your question with short, easy to understand example. Your link shows a script which is long and hard to understand, which does not help me much.